# Securely unpack malware

Tags: malware, obfuscation

I'm trying to find a way to securely unpack Windows Malware packed with UPX, I need to unpack a lot for analysis so automating the process as much as possible is beneficial.

I've found a few methods but I'm not sure on how secure it would be as I want to unpack the malware in a VM for security, store the unpacked malware on a drive and then analyse the data outside of the VM.

One method I've found is from Grey Hat Python, using PEPyEmu to run the executable and then setting a breakpoint at a jmp instruction as this can imply that execution is jumping out of unpacking and into the actual executable in this like `emu.set_mnemonic_handler( "jmp", jmp_handler )`

What if the malware writer has changed the instruction from `jmp` to `cmp eax, eax; je`, then wouldn't I then continue to execute the actual malware?

The second idea I have seen is PE Explorer but I'm not sure if this will be using the same ideas as the `jmp` instruction breakpoint.

The third idea is OmniUnpack, https://wiki.smu.edu.sg/flyer/images/2/26/OmniUnpack.pdf
which stops unpacking when a potentially dangerous system call is used. However I can't find any mention of open source code online.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any danger in unpacking a malware? I thought there's not a lot of exploits like that.. I am genuinely interested whether that ever happened with UPX.

Comment: Plus, if I were you I would analyze the malware in a VM like Flare VM (it's made for this specific purpose and it includes all steps AFAIK). Why would you want to move the malware outside of the VM when unpacked?

Comment: @SirMuffington thanks i'll give a look into Flare VM. I'm currently working on a project to classify Malware using static techniques, so I will be moving it to an OS for developing the classifier.